# Java debugging servlets

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to debug a java web application. The problem is due to something before the doGet/doPOST methods. Where do I start where do I look inside the container to debug before the doGet or how exactly is a request handled?

Comment: AFAIK you servlet life cycle is init -> doGet/doPost --> destroy
you can see in init before getting executed doGet/doPost...

Comment: You can attach a debugger to your container and tell it to pause on error.

Comment: what do you use for developing (which IDE/editor?)

Comment: Post the problem you are facing.

Comment: The problem I think is due to stuff in the web.xml eg authentication at the container level, how can this be debugged I am using eclipse.

Comment: which servlet container are you using? jetty? tomcat?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Servlet lift cycle.

```
Intit
Service(doGet/doPost)
Destroy
```

When servlet initialized init method calls so you can start debugging from the init method of the servlet and moves towards Service(doGet/doPost) method. see [Servlet Life Cycle](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Servlets4.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer depends greatly on what you load before the doGet/doPost parts of your code. Do you set up code in contextListeners, if so you start there, etc...

To better debug you should enable logging to file in the servlet container (i.e. jetty, tomcat, glassfish, whatever) to see if there is any error messages there that might be the cause of your woes...